# Pandas: read_sql bind variables

Tags: python, sql, pandas

есть следующие выдержки из кода

```
python.py
    df = pd.read_sql(con=con, sql=sql, params={'start_date': datetime,
                                                          'id_m': prd})

sql.py 
.....
and NVL(product_id,0) in (:id_m)
.....
```

Пробую передать в id_m следующие значение 'prd': "('2571','2574')"
от чего получаю пустой результат,
просьба, подсказать как корректно передать переменные в подобном случае?
соответственно мне нужно чтобы sql запрос выполнился с таким условием

```
and NVL(product_id,0) in ('2571','2574')
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А `prd` у вас всё-таки кортеж или строка? Попробуйте именно кортеж, а не строку.

Comment: @CrazyElf, строка, в итоге переписал через regexp_like, на выходе получаю то что нужно, буду дальше тестировать,